# STM32F4 taking 2 minutes to enter DFU

Tags: stm32

We're having problems at the moment getting our device (STM32F405ZGT6) to enter DFU mode, or rather, we can enter it, but it always takes a little over 2 minutes to appear.

We have a push button switch on the board to enter into DFU. If you let go of the switch at any point before the 2 minutes it will boot into application memory.

When it finally enters DFU mode it behaves as expected.

Interestingly, this will only work on the Mac.

Attempting the same on Windows, holding the button in while cycling power, Windows will straight away detect an 'unknown device' even after installing the drivers included in the Dfuse demo application folder. Trying to manually install the driver against this 'unknown device' then returns 'the device cannot start'.

We have also implemented a 'jump to bootloader' routine within our main application, which shuts down various things before jumping to the internal bootloader. Using this method on Windows will bring the 'unknown device connected' message in Windows. Using this method on Mac, nothing is ever detected.

How can I get the device drivers to enter DFU mode in a timely manner on our STM32F4?

Comment: I had a similar issue for a Windows PC being used for board testing and it was apparently due to the driver being loaded for each board (trying to use STM32 DFU system memory boot mode). As an alternative, I created a USB CDC device class for testing the port with a USB VCP driver and used a fixed common USB serial number. The common VID,PID and serial number prevented having to wait for a new driver reload. The common serial number was permissible for us since it was only test code (one board at a time). I have no idea why Windows was taking so long to install a driver that was already used.

Comment: Another option: Disable internet access (temporary). When it detects a new device, Windows likes to check its update repository for driver updates - that can take *forever*.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are **not** using the same VID:PID pair as the bootloader. This would confuse operating systems resulting in a wrong driver assignment.

> We have also implemented a 'jump to bootloader' routine within our main application, which shuts down various things before jumping to the internal bootloader

You want to disconnect on the USB bus properly befor jumping to the bootloader. The easiest method is to reconfigure the USB pins in GPIO mode and drive them with a low output for one second, then start the bootloader afterwards.

Now the OS will see a *new* device once the bootloader activates USB again, since the one second with both bus data lines down was detected as device removal.

Comment: Thanks for this Turbo, will investigate now.
Going from what dfu-util says the vid/pid is 0483:df11

Found DFU: [0483:df11] ver=2200, devnum=8, cfg=1, intf=0, path="0-4", alt=3, name="@Device Feature/0xFFFF0000/01*004 e", serial="356232763233"